# How to create satellite assembly for form's resources?

Tags: c#, winforms, localization

Setting the form's `Localizable` property to true will create a `.resx` file for the fallback locale.

But if I want to have additional locales in separate assemblies, how do I get to put the form's `.resx` files in those assemblies?

Answer (score 2):

Open the form in the designer.

Select the form and open the properties window.

Locate the Language property. Select whatever language you want to want to use.

Select a string property on the form and enter a text (if possible, in the new language).

Visual Studio will now automatically generate a .resx file for the new language and store the new text in that .resx file.

Compile your project.

Visual Studio will automatically generate the satellite dll in a subdirectory below the output directory, with the standard abbreviation (a.k.a. IEFT tag) for the language.

You will probably want to switch the language of the form back to "default" afterwards.

Comment: Also for non-UI parts, for example for a resource file like `Resources.Resx` which is under `Properties` folder, you can add the localized version of file by adding locale name in file name, for example  `Resources.fa-IR.Resx` then after building the application you will have those resource also in a satellite assembly in `\bin\Debug\fa-IR` folder.